# How can I print a string with the same length with or without multicharacters?

Tags: c, character-encoding

I am trying to do ***exercise 1-22*** in K&R book. It asks to fold long lines (i.e.going into a new line) after a predefined number of characters in string.

As I was testing the program and it worked well, but I saw that some lines were "folding" earlier than they should.  I noticed that it was the lines on which special characters appeared, such as:

> ö ş ç ğ

So, my question is, how do I ensure that lines are printed with the same maximum length with or without multicharacters?

Comment: I guess your strings are encoded in [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), where all bytes after the first byte in a multi.byte codepoint follow the pattern `10xxxxxx`. Ignore these bytes when you count the length and make sure not to break up multi-byte sequences.

Comment: And hopefully you aren't dealing with decomposed characters (where the diacritics are separate from the base character).

Comment: Handling emoji with their attributes is a variation on the theme of decomposed characters, too.  Fun times ahead.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon.  We'll help you fix code that shows an honest attempt to solve the problem and describes the issues you're having.  Without the code, you're running the risk of your question being considered 'too broad' or 'off-topic for lack of an MCVE ([MCVE])'.

Comment: But isn't ignoring those bytes also means ignoring the characters? @MOehm

Comment: Read http://unicode.org/reports/tr29/ especially about grapheme clusters.

Comment: No. You don't discard the characters when you print, you only ignore them when you determine the width of the string, i.e. the number of unicode characters your byte string represents. For example, if you have a string that begins with "Hü", where the H takes 1 byte and the ü takes 2 bytes, and you want to break after the second unicode character, you must break your string after the third byte. (But as others have pointed out, there are more things to consider here.)

Comment: But if you want them to be visibly the same length there is no substitute for rendering the glyphs and computing pixel width.

Comment: I tried to search the internet about these characters and basically I could'nt find or understand enough to write a code. I can post a code to show the string length and you can see that at these characters are considered 2 bytes. But other than that, I don't think I asked a question that is too broad @JonathanLeffler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What happens in your code ?**

The K&R was written in a time where all characters were encoded on one single char.  Example of such encoding standards are [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) or [ISO 8859](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859).

Nowadays the leading encoding standard is UNICODE, which comes in several flavors. The [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoding is used to represent the thousands of unicode characters on 8 bit bytes, using a variable length scheme:

- the ascii characters (i.e. 0x00 to 0x7F)  are encoded on a single byte.
- all other characters are encoded on 2 to 4 bytes.

So the [letter ö](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00f6/index.htm) and the others in your list are encoded as 2 consecutive bytes.  Unfortunately, the standard C library and the algorithms of K&R do not manage variable encoding. So each of your special char is counted as two so that your algorithm is tricked.

**How to solve it ?**

There is no easy way.  You must make a distinction between the length of the strings in memory, and the length of the strings when they are displayed.

I can propose you a trick that uses the properties of the encoding scheme:  whenever you count the display length of a string, just ignore the characters c in memory that comply with the condition c&0xC0==0x80.

Another way would be to use wide chars `wchar_t`/`win_t` (requires header `wchar.h`) instead of `char`/`int` and use `getwc()`/`putwc()` instead of `getc()`/`putc()`.  If on your environment `sizeof(wchar_t)` is 4 then you will be able to work with unicode just using the wide characters and wide library functions instead of the normal ones mentioned in K&R.  If however
`sizeof(wchar_t)` is smaller (for example 2), you could work correctly with a larger subset of unicode but still could encounter alignement issues in some cases.

Comment: May I ask what does the `c&0xC0==0x80` condition mean?

Comment: UV for `c & 0xC0 == 0x80`.

Comment: `0xC0` in binary is `1100 0000`.  `&` ensures that all the bits where there is 0 a cleared to 0 (chapter 2.9 of K&R on the bitwise logical operations).  So if you have the binary representation of `c` being `XYzz zzzz`, then `c&0xC0` will result in `XY00 0000`. 0x80 in binary is `1000 0000`.  So `c&0xC0==0x80` is true if and only if  `c` in binary is like `10zz zzzz` .  If you look at the [multibyte encoding of UTF8 on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description) you'll notice that only butes that are encoded as `10xx xxxx` are only the subsequent bytes on a multibyte encoding.

Answer (score 0):

As in the comment, your string is probably encoded in UTF-8. That means that some characters, including the ones you mention, use more than one byte. If you simply count bytes to determine the width of your output, your computed value may be too large.

To properly determine the number of characters in a string with multibyte characters, use a function such as [mbrlen(3)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mbrlen.html).

You can use [mbrtowc(3)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mbrtowc.html) to find out the number of bytes of the first character in a string, if you're counting character for character.

This of course goes way beyond the scope of the K&R book. It was written before multibyte characters were used.

Comment: You are of course completely right with `mbrlen()` ! But the first chapter of K&R is really about the basics.  The only library functions that are used in it are the basic I/O  functions, and counting characters and lines is handled with loops.

Comment: I tried to understand the function but couldn't do it. As I become comfortable with pointers and C language as a whole, I will definitely try this. Thanks for the answer.